# pg_restore what is frequency of commit when inserting data

Tags: postgresql

When using pg_restore to restore archive contents in a database, how often commits are executed? I cannot find any answer in the documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is documented by exception--the default applies except for where it is documented not to.

If you don't specify `-1` or `--single-transaction`, then it runs in (the default) autocommit mode.  Meaning each SQL statement commits itself upon success.  Each COPY therefore is one large transaction of the while table data.